# NestJS : Not able to use Apollo Studio Explorer

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo

I'm trying to use Apollo Studio Explorer with NestJS graphql (express server). I'm adding ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault in the plugins array of GraphQLModule.

It fails with this exception:

```
error TS2322: Type 'ApolloServerPlugin<BaseContext>' is not assignable to type 'ApolloServerPlugin<any>'.
  Types of property 'serverWillStart' are incompatible.
    Type '(service: GraphQLServiceContext) => Promise<void | GraphQLServerListener>' is not assignable to type '(service: GraphQLServerContext) => Promise<void | GraphQLServerListener>'.
      Types of parameters 'service' and 'service' are incompatible.
        Type 'GraphQLServerContext' is missing the following properties from type 'GraphQLServiceContext': schemaHash, serverlessFramework

43       plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
```

This is how I configured it in the code -

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ApolloDriver, ApolloDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { join } from 'path';
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } from 'apollo-server-core';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          type: 'postgres',
          logging: true,
          host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
          port: +configService.get<number>('DB_PORT'),
          username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
          password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
          database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
          entities: [join(__dirname, '**', '*.entity.{ts,js}')],
          synchronize: true,
        } as TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions;
      },
    }),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      playground: true,
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      context: ({ req }) => ({ headers: req.headers }),
      definitions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.schema.ts'),
        outputAs: 'class',
      },
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
    })
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class DomainModule {}
```

NestJS details-

```
| \ | |           | |    |_  |/  ___|/  __ \| |   |_   _|
|  \| |  ___  ___ | |_     | |\ `--. | /  \/| |     | |
| . ` | / _ \/ __|| __|    | | `--. \| |    | |     | |
| |\  ||  __/\__ \| |_ /\__/ //\__/ /| \__/\| |_____| |_
\_| \_/ \___||___/ \__|\____/ \____/  \____/\_____/\___/


[System Information]
OS Version     : macOS Unknown
NodeJS Version : v16.15.0
NPM Version    : 8.5.5 

[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 9.4.0 

[Nest Platform Information]
devtools-integration version : 0.1.4
platform-express version     : 9.4.0
schematics version           : 9.1.0
graphql version              : 11.0.5
typeorm version              : 9.0.1
testing version              : 9.4.0
apollo version               : 11.0.5
common version               : 9.4.0
config version               : 2.3.1
core version                 : 9.4.0
cli version                  : 9.4.0
```

Is there anything missing here? I think it was working fine until @nestjs/apollo version ^10.0.2 whereas I'm using 11.0.5.

Comment: Did you happen to find the solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I could resolve this error by changing the import statement.

import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } from '@apollo/server/plugin/landingPage/default';

Comment: Yeah that solution worked for me too:

import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } from '@apollo/server/plugin/landingPage/default';

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the latest version of nest.js and apollo, using the correct import mentioned by you. Any other ideas?

Comment: For this particular issue, I had to update my npm packages. I was using `apollo-server-core`, but I had to update to `@apollo/server` and use its imports instead.